# Computing expectation of truncated conditional Gaussian r.v.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

I have random variables $(Z,Z_k)\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ and $\bar{y}=\boldsymbol{1}\{Z>-C\}$ for some fixed constant $C$. I would like to compute $\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,\bar{y}]$ without using any integration. In what follows, I will outline how I'll do it. We have
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,\bar{y}]
    &\stackrel{(a)}{=}\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,\bar{y},Z>-C]\mathbb{P}[Z>-C|Z_k,\bar{y}] \\
    &\qquad+\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,\bar{y},Z\leq-C|Z_k,\bar{y}]\mathbb{P}[Z\leq-C|Z_k,\bar{y}] \\
    &\stackrel{(b)}{=}\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,Z>-C]\boldsymbol{1}\{\bar{y}=1\}
    +\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,Z\leq-C]\boldsymbol{1}\{\bar{y}=0\},
\end{align*}
where (a) is by the towering property of expectation, and (b) is by noting that $\bar{y}$ and $Z>-C$ describes the same event. Next, we introduce the definition of a truncated Gaussian random variable. Note that $\boldsymbol{1}\{\cdot\}$ is the indicator function.

**Definition:** Given $Z$ is a Gaussian random variable, then $(Z|z_l<Z<z_u)$, where $-\infty\leq z_l<z_u\leq\infty$, is a *truncated Gaussian random variable* with mean
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[Z|z_l<Z<z_u]
    &=\mathbb{E}[Z]-\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z]}\frac{\phi(\frac{z_u-\mathbb{E}[Z]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z]}})-\phi(\frac{z_l-\mathbb{E}[Z]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z]}})}{\Phi(\frac{z_u-\mathbb{E}[Z]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z]}})-\Phi(\frac{z_l-\mathbb{E}[Z]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z]}})},
\end{align}
where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the standard Gaussian pdf and $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard Gaussian cdf.

Applying this definition, we have
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k,\bar{y}]
    &=\bigg(\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]+\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}\frac{\phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}{1-\Phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}\bigg)\boldsymbol{1}\{\bar{y}=1\} \\
    &\qquad+\bigg(\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]-\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}\frac{\phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}{\Phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}\bigg)\boldsymbol{1}\{\bar{y}=0\} \\
    &=\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]+\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}\bigg(\frac{\phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}{1-\Phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}\boldsymbol{1}\{\bar{y}=1\}-\frac{\phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}{\Phi(\frac{-C-\mathbb{E}[Z|Z_k]}{\sqrt{\text{Var}[Z|Z_k]}})}\boldsymbol{1}\{\bar{y}=0\}\bigg)
\end{align}
Is this the correct way to do it? More specifically, does the truncated Gaussian definition transfer over to **conditional** expectations? Thanks.

Comment: Simplify, distill.

Comment: I don't see a way to simplify further.